# Confidence intervals for across-items (not across-subjects!) Pearson's R

Tags: correlation, confidence-interval, pearson-r

For each of $N=30$ subjects, I am computing a Pearson's $R$ value to reflect how well two variables $X$ and $Y$ correlate for that subject, where variables $X$ and $Y$ represent subject-wise ratings for individual stimuli (items).

Does it make sense to compute a 95% confidence interval for each of these $R$'s, given that said CI would normally (I think) be meant to reflect an underlying population value, whereas in my case each $R$ is obtained not from an across-subject, but from an across-item correlation?

Comment: Could your items not be thought of as being sampled from a population of possible items?

Comment: That's what I'm wondering as well - I'm not sure if the meaning of the term 'population', as per the stats texts where the above definition was taken (talking about the "underlying population value"), is to be taken literally (population of individuals) or more generally (population of any items, as opposed to only a sample of them).

Comment: I can't speak for the stats texts you've read, but generally speaking when we talk about populations it's in a more general sense than a group of people. If I want to estimate the mean lifespan of, e.g., VW Golfs then my my population is all VW Golfs.